# X DNA match without autosomal match but no match with his mother

Tags: ancestry.com

My husband and I have an X DNA match of 190cM but no autosomal. His mother and I don't match unless you put it down to 3. This doesn't seem to follow any pattern.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Is your question "How can my husband share more cM with me than his mother does?"?  If so, please use the [edit] button beneath your question to make what you are asking clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Your husband and his mother should have the X DNA match of 190cM. That is the full X chromosome.

Your husband and you should not have a significant X DNA match if you're not related and you say you have no autosomal in common.

If GEDmatch is actually showing you that, then GEDmatch has made some sort of analysis mistake (it happens sometimes). If that is the case, I would try deleting those three tests from GEDmatch (under EDIT or DELETE your DNA resource profiles) and then upload them again.  If that doesn't work, you can try an email to GEDmatch@Gmail.com and they might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you inherit your X-DNA not only from your mother but also from your father. And algorithms can't distinguish what is the origin of each part of X-DNA. So your X-DNA match is false-positive or IBS.

Comment: The odd thing is we did a test with 23andme and we have a match on the 4th chromosome but none on the X.